# Mock variable in function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

For unit testing, I want to mock a variable inside a function, such as:

```
def function_to_test(self):
    foo = get_complex_data_structure()  # Do not test this
    do_work(foo)  # Test this
```

I my unit test, I don't want to be dependent on what `get_complex_data_structure()` would return, and therefore want to set the value of foo manually.

How do I accomplish this? Is this the place for `@patch.object`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use [`@patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) to mock out `get_complex_data_structure()`:

```
@patch('module_under_test.get_complex_data_structure')
def test_function_to_test(self, mocked_function):
    foo_mock = mocked_function.return_value
```

When the test function then calls `get_complex_data_structure()` a mock object is returned and stored in the local name `foo`; the very same object that `mocked_function.return_value` references in the above test; you can use that value to test if `do_work()` got passed the right object, for example.

Comment: How can we mock when get_complex_data_structure() has some parameters and called two times returning two different values foo1 and foo2 ? Above given solution will generate same mocked values for foo1 and foo2

Comment: @chintan-p-bhatt: then set [`Mock.side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect), either to an iterable (and Python will use the next value from that iterable for each call), or a function; a function is given the same arguments so you can return a value based on those.

Comment: @chintan-p-bhatt: You can't use multiple lines in comments, or code blocks; only `\`` single backticks work. You don't need to show me how you managed to get it to work, here are [other answers I gave on mocking that use `.side_effect`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+*.side_effect) that you could reference. If you have a new question, you could create a new post on that.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that get_complex_data_structure is a function<sup>1</sup>, you can just patch it using any of the various [mock.patch utilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers):

```
with mock.patch.object(the_module, 'get_complex_data_structure', return_value=something)
  val = function_to_test()
  ...
```

they can be used as decorators or context managers or explicitly started and stopped using the `start` and `stop` methods.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>If it's not a function, you can always factor that code out into a simple utility function which returns the complex data-structure</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>There are a million ways to use mocks -- It pays to read the docs to figure out all the ways that you can set the return value, etc.</sup>