# Unable to mock variable in a function of a class

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to mock a class method that gets called within another class method.

```py
from omdenalore.natural_language_processing.topic_modelling import TopicModelling
from unittest import mock


def test_process_words(load_spacy_model):
    tm = TopicModelling()
    with mock.patch.object(
        TopicModelling.process_words, "TextPreprocessor.load_model", return_value=load_spacy_model
    ):
        processed_words = tm.process_words()
        assert processed_words
```

`TopicModelling class`

```
from omdenalore.natural_language_processing.preprocess_text import (
    TextPreprocessor,
)

class TopicModelling:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def process_words(self):
        model = TextPreprocessor.load_model() # trying to mock this 
        # do some stuff with model
```

But I keep getting an error `AttributeError: <function TopicModelling.process_words at 0x7fb1a2787c20> does not have the attribute 'TextPreprocessor.load_model'`.

`load_spacy_model` is a fixture that I want to patch the function `TextPreprocessor.load_model()` with.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649214/mock-variable-in-function) which I referred to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your code:

- you are trying to patch the method `TextPreprocessor.load_model`, but instead you mock `TopicModelling.process_words`, and you do so in the namespace under test instead of that where `TextPreprocessor.load_model` is imported;
- `tm` should be instantiated within the `with` statement, not before it.

So, I would suggest instead the following test script:

```py
from omdenalore.natural_language_processing.topic_modelling import TopicModelling


def test_process_words(mocker):
    # Patch where load_model is called
    process_words = mocker.patch(
        "omdenalore.natural_language_processing.topic_modelling.TextPreprocessor.load_model",
        return_value=load_spacy_model,
    )
    # Instantiate and call
    tm = TopicModelling()
    processed_words = tm.process_words()

    assert processed_words
```

Comment: I needed to install `pytest-mock`, then use `load_spacy_model()` which is a fixture as I previously used it to monkeypatch which needed to yield a function. Now it works!