# How to do pytest to show method has been called with specified types of arguments?

Tags: mocking, pytest, magicmock

My code is as below:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = myClient()

    def myMethod(self):
        query = Query()
        response = self.client.post(data=query)
```

So now I'd like to introduce code change from `data=query` to `data=query.__dict__`, so how to design pytest and Mock() to test `self.client.post` has been called with passing in `data=query.__dict__` rather than `data=query`?

Comment: this may answer your question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649214/mock-variable-in-function

Answer (score 0):

So, given this code in **mymodule.py**:

```py
class myClient:
    def post(self, data):
        ...


class Query:
    pass


class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = myClient()

    def myMethod(self):
        query = Query()
        response = self.client.post(data=query)
```

You can set your test like this in **test_mymodule.py** (same directory):

```py
import pytest
from mymodule import myClass, Query


@pytest.fixture
def post(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("temp.myClient.post")


def test_myMethod_with_class(post):
    myclass = myClass()
    myclass.myMethod()
    assert isinstance(post.call_args[1]["data"], Query)
```

In which case pytest reports `1 test passed`.

Now, if you replace "query" with "query.__dict__" in the above code, pytest will report `1 failed`, so you have to change it like this:

```py
def test_myMethod_with_dict(post):
    myclass = myClass()
    myclass.myMethod()
    assert isinstance(post.call_args[1]["data"], dict)
```

And once again pytest reports `1 test passed`.